# VBA-Loop with some worksheets

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am a beginner and I would like to do a loop in all the worksheets of my excel file, except the first one. However the code below only works on the second one. Could you please explain me what is wrong in this code?

Many thanks

```
Sub MobileTCalculation()
'MobileTCalculation Macro
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 40
Worksheets(1 + 1).Select
Range("A20").Select
On Error Resume Next
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip the first sheet then change the loop as shown below. `Worksheets(i + 1)` will give you errors if there are only 40 sheets in your workbook ;)

Use this

```
Sub MobileTCalculation()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 40
        Worksheets(i).Range("A20").Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Also two things.

**1)** Use of `On Error Resume Next` is evil ;) Use it only when necessary.

**2)** Don't use `.SELECT` It slows down your code. Instead directly perform the action. For example

```
Sub MobileTCalculation()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 40
        With Worksheets(i).Range("A20")
            Debug.Print .Value
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: It doesn't feel right using a `For i = x to y` rather than a `For Each` but it does save adding a worksheet index test. +1

Comment: I agree with you. I normally use `For Each` and then compare the sheet names that I want to avoid. In this scenario, I am not sure how many sheets are there in total. If there are 50 sheets and the user wants to loop through 2 - 40 then I believe, `For i = x to y` is a better idea. :)

Comment: For scalability I suggest: `For i = 2 To Sheets.Count`

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
Worksheets(1 + 1).Select
```

so it uses your `i` variable... you've just put `1 + 1` so it always evaluates to `2`

A classic mistake :)

Comment: Lol Thank you! Did not see that I put a 1 instead of a "i"!